# dynamic code style rather than hard coding

Tags: php, mysql, webserver

when inserting updating i use to

```
 $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO emp_detail  VALUES ('%s')", implode ("', '",$formData));
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
```

is that above coding style cause server machine slow down.rather than coding like just below.

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO emp_detail  VALUES ('aa','bbb','ccc');
 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
```

i mean execution time,perfomance etc..

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: There is no noticeable difference from either performance or execution time perspective.

Comment: That could make your application run a lot faster after someone submits a `DROP TABLE` statement.

Comment: @tadman: could you give a real example with `DROP TABLE` that **would** work?

Comment: There's a [tool](http://sqlmap.org/) that can do all kinds of things like this if you configure it correctly. If that list of features doesn't scare you into writing solid, secure queries, nothing will. I'm not posting examples here, you can find them yourself if you read up on [SQL injection problems](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @tadman: the thing is - you **CANNOT** `DROP TABLE` using this code. You won't post an example here - because it's impossible. And bobby table example here is irrelevant. It just won't work.

Comment: Why are you so certain? Where did you call `mysql_real_escape_string` on every single one of the values in that array?

Comment: @tadman: there is no such call. But that doesn't mean you could do that. That's why I asked an example. Is it that difficult for you to provide one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in execution time would be hard to measure, as string interpolation and an `implode` call is going to be orders of magnitude faster than the round-trip time to the database server. We're talking nanoseconds versus milliseconds.

You're asking the wrong question, though. It's a really bad practice to be writing out literal SQL statements inside your application, it's way too low-level to be sustainable within any non-trivial application.

What you should be using is something like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) to manage your database contents. A framework like [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) or [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) also eliminates a lot of this super low-level implementation.

Remember when you're using `mysql_query`, you're interfacing directly with the MySQL C driver. This is a terribly bad idea and is actually deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, generating warnings. You should not be using this in new applications. At the very least use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) to provide a better wrapper around MySQL.

Comment: "This is a terribly bad idea" --- why working with "MySQL C driver" is a bad idea? And doesn't PDO use the same driver? If not - how it interacts with mysql then?

Comment: `mysql_query` is dangerous by default, it doesn't do any escaping, and even one mistake can be enough for your site to be completely subverted by a SQL injection hacking tool. This is an unacceptable risk. PDO does a lot to avoid these problems by providing a safe, easy to audit method of writing queries. Low-level drivers are intended to be used by things like PDO and not your high-level application code.

Comment: how is it related to the driver? PDO doesn't escape automagically as well and uses the same driver as mysql_* functions do. And just so you know - PDO by default uses prepared statements emulation, which in fact is identical to escaping.

Comment: PDO *does* escape automatically if you use SQL placeholders, which is an absolute **must** for modern applications. Emulated or not, placeholders provide certainty that the data will be escaped properly, every time, and eliminates the risk of missing an injection point. I don't know why you're fighting me on this. `mysql_query` is officially deprecated and produces warnings in PHP 5.5. Stop using it. Period. The 1990s are *over*.

Comment: I agree it's deprecated, but "you're interfacing directly with the MySQL C driver. This is a terribly bad idea" statement hasn't enough technical background explanation. And from my perspective it's just nonsense. "prepared statements are good" - is a good explanation. Referring to a underlying driver (which is just incorrect) isn't

Comment: To be as specific as possible: Using low-level drivers in your high-level application should be a **last resort** and not standard operating procedure.

Comment: mysql_* is the wrapper over driver exactly like the PDO. They are identical from this point of view. With PDO you can follow the procedural style which is 99% alike the mysql_*

Comment: You're really a big fan of `mysql_query` aren't you? Does it support placeholders? No. Does it make escaping easy and reliable? No. Is it deprecated and scheduled for removal? Yes. That is not the same thing as PDO *at all*. This is like arguing that Visual Basic and Haskell are the same thing since they're both Turing Complete.

Comment: I'm not a fan, I've just said that your statement when you mention mysql C driver is incorrect from technical perspective. That's it, nothing more. Both pdo and mysql_* rely on the same mysql client.

Comment: If you look at the MySQL C library you can see that the first "driver" put into PHP is little more than the methods in there being given PHP equivalents. That's it. There is no more direct way to interface with the driver in PHP. PDO's API is entirely different and does a lot more than simply map calls.

Comment: When I say "interfacing directly" I mean using those literal methods without anything in the way of higher level functionality. Unless you're writing a driver like PDO you shouldn't ever need to concern yourself with the details of the MySQL C driver.